# Does TeamCity use Jenkins behind the scenes?

Tags: jenkins, teamcity

My colleague told me that TeamCity is just Jenkins with a different frontend (as in Teamcity uses Jenkins behind..).

Is that true? I can't find that information anywhere online.

Comment: Surely you've been here long enough to realise that this question isn't going to get a good response?

Comment: Well, it is code related, not subjective and someone might know the answer and I can't find the information on Google. So I guess that's a legit question, no?

Comment: It's getting downvoted...

Comment: You can also ask: "Is Windows using Linux behind the scenes?" I think, thats why.

Comment: I think that's perfectly fine, and the answer is no.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question +1. Chill out people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it isn't true - they are different products and neither of them is based on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend probably meant that they both are for same purpose (Continuous Integration). Other than that there is no relation between them, they are different products from different vendors for relatively same purpose (Continuous Integration). You can see [Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software) to compare different CI software.

Comment: Nah, he really meant that they use the same CI engine behind (in an argument saying we would have the same problems using Jenkins and TC)